# How to properly use request(get)?

Tags: python, pandas

I am able to get a response from the API by using the following in Pandas:

```
call_eia=requests.get('https://api.eia.gov/v2/nuclear-outages/facility-nuclear-outages/data?api_key=XXXX)
```

However after that I am not sure how to access the data properly, I have tried this but it not a data frame like I need it.

```
data = call_eia.text
```

[Screenshot of the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztbFN.png)

[Screenshot of call_eia.text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFd1r.png)

Comment: what's the content of `call_eia.text`

Comment: added to initial post :)

Answer (score 1):

The API returns JSON which you access through the Response object. You can then pass that directly to a Dataframe constructor.

```
import requests
import pandas

params = {'api_key': '9999999999999999'}
try:
    (r := requests.get('https://api.eia.gov/v2/nuclear-outages/facility-nuclear-outages/data', params=params)).raise_for_status()
    dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(r.json())
    print(dataframe)
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Data acquisition failed due to {e}')
```

**Note:**

Depending on what you want to do with these data you may not even need a dataframe. r.json() will return a dictionary. You may be able to work directly with that